# Organic Internet SCP Extension - Show Configurable Options in Order Email & PDF

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, transactional-mail

I've made the necessary changes to Organic Internet's **"Simple Configurable Product"** extension so that all configurable options are displayed in the Admin Panel (Sales > Orders). However, I'm having trouble displaying configurable options in the order email and invoice PDF. I tried copying

```
/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

and

```
/template/sales/order/items.phtml
```

to my template but that did not work. Has anyone solved this SCP extension issue?